# How to bind steam client to a different IP address?

Tags: steam, windows-7, networking

So I have 2 network cards, and multiple networks (VPN, etc).

What I want to do is bind steam client to one of my IPs, and bypass my VPN (because lag).

I checked all the steam settings and launching options but I don't see anything related to what I want to do.

Any ideas? I'm using the Windows steam client on Windows 7.

Comment: I highly doubt you can achieve things like that with a game client. It simply wouldn't be cost-effective for Steam to program a feature like this. Maybe you could try a third party tool to redirect all network traffic originating from Steam?

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is with IP routing tables. You should give the VPNs routes so that they only get traffic for the networks that are connected. In an ideal world these routes would be properly set up on the VPN server, but most sys admins don't bother and end up stealing all of your traffic.

There should be plenty of information on the internet on how to do this. Take a look at the command line `route` command, start with `route print`. One of the other stack exchange sites (maybe super user) is probably a better place to ask about how to set up the routes properly.